# Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL?' to expected argument type 'URL'

Tags: swift, uiwebview

The error message I get from this code segment is "cannot convert value of type 'NSURL?' to expected argument type 'URL'". When I go onto my web browser, I can see the pdf file so I know it is working. The pdf files are stored a remote server. Please help!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    print("dir2: \(dir2) dir1: \(dir1)")
    let targetURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/\(dir1)/\(dir2).pdf")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: targetURL) //this is the line with error.
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: which line exactly giving the error, and swift version? Try this: 
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: targetURL!)

Comment: let request = NSURLRequest(URL: targetURL) is the line that is giving the error. I am using swift version 3.

Comment: Simply use `URL` and `URLRequest` instead of their `NS` counterparts – and then unwrap `targetURL`, as it might not be a valid URL.

Comment: Thank you Hamish! It worked!

Answer (score 2):

For these lines:

```
    let targetURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/\(dir1)/\(dir2).pdf")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: targetURL)
```

Replace the NSURL with URL and NSURequest with URLRequest.

Your code should be:

```
    let targetURL = URL(string: "http://example.com/\(dir1)/\(dir2).pdf")
    let request = URLRequest(url: targetURL!)
```